# How to pass parameter to js.erb in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to an ajax request to call `user` controller's `xyz` action with the passed parameter `stage` and then append it on `#the_box` so that I can perform conditional operation like for stage `x` append `@user.age`, for stage `y` append `@user.age+1` and for stage `z` append `@user.age-1`. How should I do?

I have a html.erb file contains such code:

```
<center>
  <%= link_to "A", xyz_user_path, stage: "x", remote: true %>
  <%= link_to "B", xyz_user_path, stage: "y", remote: true %>
  <%= link_to "C", xyz_user_path, stage: "z", remote: true %>
</center>
<div id="the_box"></div>
```

and `users_controller.rb` has

```
before_action :set_user, only: [ :xyz]

def xyz
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {}
    end
end

private
def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

and this `xyz.js.erb` is what I have now but cannot deal with parameter so it cannot handle conditional operation

```
$("#the_box").append("<%= @user.age%>");
```

Comment: You can remove the brackets after format.js in the response.

Comment: Is there any difference?

Comment: Yep - I'll explain for you

Answer (score 6):

The other answers will help you on here - let me explain them

---

**format.js**

When you use `format.js` to filter the `mime types`, opening brackets basically tells Rails that you want to perform some custom functionality (and hence it won't load the `[action].js.erb` as default)

If you want to just invoke `[action].js.erb`, you'll have to call the following:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.js #-> will just call [action].js.erb
end
```

You'll want to read up more about [Rails mime types (how to determine XHR requests)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Mime/Type.html) & the [`respond_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to) block

---

**@instance_variables**

Secondly, you need to consider the role of `@instance variables` in your application, and consequently, the method in question.

The main issue you have is you're calling `@user` in a method which doesn't define it - hence you'll likely see the error `undefined method ___ for nil:NilClass` or similar

You must remember that [Rails is just a gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails) - a series of classes which runs on the Ruby language. This means that each time you wish to perform a method on an "object" / piece of data, you'll have you to declare / create the object in your Rails application:

```
def xyz
   @user = User.find params[:id] #-> sets the variable for the duration of the "instance"
   ...
end
```

Please take note of the *name* of the variable -- an *instance* variable. By setting `@user` (instance variables are always defined with an `@`), you basically give Rails the ability to access the data inside it for as long as the *class* which defines the variable is invoked.

Basically means that if you set `@user = User.find`, it will be available through your `view` & other helper methods called from the instance of the class

---

**Fix**

Finally, to address your question directly:

> I want to an ajax request to call user controller's xyz action with
>   the passed parameter stage and then append it on #the_box so that I
>   can perform conditional operation like for stage x append @user.age,
>   for stage y append @user.age+1 and for stage z append @user.age-1. How
>   should I do?

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   get "xyz/:stage" #-> domain.com/users/:user_id/xyz/:stage
end

#app/views/users/your_view.html.erb
<% links = [["A", "x"], ["B", "y"], ["C", "z"]] %>
<% links.each do |link, stage| %>
    <%= link_to link, xyz_user_path(user, stage: stage), remote: true %>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def xyz
      case params[:stage]
        when "x"
          @user.increment!(:age)
        when "y"
          @user.decrement!(:age)
      end
      respond_to do |format|
         format.js
      end
   end
end

#app/views/users/xyz.js.erb
$("#the_box").append("<%=j @user.age %>");
```

Comment: just wanted to say all around great answer with lots of info

Comment: What do you mean by calling @user in a method which doesn't define it? Is `before_action :set_user, only: [ :xyz]` not proper? Actually I don't know the mechanism how @user is passed to xyz.js.erb and what class xyz.js.erb belongs to.

Comment: Hey Marcus, sorry about that - I *did* see your call to `set_user`, but *after* I'd written my answer. I left it in for simplicity sake

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the parameter in the helper like this:

```
xyz_user_path(stage: "x")
```

And then in your js.erb you can access it like:

```
<%= params['stage'] %>
```

Comment: It is not working. Does xyz.js.erb export a javascript file for browser to read? If so I may check what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm going to access an instance variable defined in wish_me action.

**controllers/jserb_controller.rb code:**

```
class JserbController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
  def wish_me
    @test = 'Hi how are you?'
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

**/views/jserb/index.html.erb code:**

```
<div class="wish-me"></div>
<%= link_to "Wish Me", wishme_path, remote: true %>
```

**/views/jserb/wish_me.js.erb**

```
$(".wish-me").append("<%=j @test %>");
```

**config/routes.rb code:**

```
match '/index' => 'jserb#index'
match '/wishme' => 'jserb#wish_me', :as => :wishme
```

Now try to hit `http://<domain-name>/index` and then click on WishMe
link. So now you are able to pass instance variable to js.erb and accessed the same.